# mark row as outlier using Tukey's fence function

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a column G that indicates the group and a continuous variable C. How can I mark each row as outlier, using for example, a Tukey's fence function as define by a function [here](http://www.questionflow.org/2017/12/26/combined-outlier-detection-with-dplyr-and-ruler/):

```
isnt_out_tukey <- function(x, k = 1.5, na.rm = TRUE) {
  quar <- quantile(x, probs = c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = na.rm)
  iqr <- diff(quar)

  (quar[1] - k * iqr <= x) & (x <= quar[2] + k * iqr)
}
```

Ultimately, I want to end up with a column O which contains a 'yes' for outlier and 'no' for no outlier for each group.

Comment: Somewhat off topic, I'd recommend using TRUE and FALSE as your ultimate outlier column output as this is much more useful in subsequent steps.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(G) %>% mutate(is_outlier = !isnt_out_tukey(C))`?